# How to get the size of a label before it is laid out?

Tags: javafx, label, size

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074024/how-to-get-label-getwidth-in-javafx) old answer on how to accomplish this. But since it involves using `impl_processCSS(boolean)`, a method that is now deprecated, I think we need to update the answer.

I've tried placing the label inside a HBox and then get the size of it, or getting the size of the HBox, without any luck. And I've also tried using .label.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth().

SSCCE:
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;

```
public class SSCCE extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        Label label = new Label("foo");
        System.out.println(label.getWidth());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see related question: [How to calculate the pixel width of a String in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015698/how-to-calculate-the-pixel-width-of-a-string-in-javafx)

Comment: I ended up using the answer in that question instead of the answer below ,since I couldn't use a `Scene` object. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Since JavaFX 8, the method you are looking for is `applyCss()`.

As JavaDoc states:

> apply styles to this Node and its children, if any. This method does not normally need to be invoked directly but may be used in conjunction with Parent.layout() to size a Node before the next pulse, or if the Scene is not in a Stage.

So you need to have the node in the container, and this one already on the scene, and also call `layout()`.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    Label label = new Label("foo bla bla");
    root.getChildren().add(label);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    root.applyCss();
    root.layout();
    System.out.println(label.getWidth());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Being the output: 17.818359375

Note I've changed `HBox` for `Group`, since:

> a Group will "auto-size" its managed resizable children to their preferred sizes during the layout pass to ensure that Regions and Controls are sized properly as their state changes

If you use an `HBox`, you need to set also the dimensions of the scene:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    HBox root = new HBox();
    Label label = new Label("foo");
    root.getChildren().add(label);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,100,20);

    root.applyCss();
    root.layout();
    System.out.println(label.getWidth());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Now the output is: 18.0

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful! But is there any way of doing this without putting the group into a Scene? I'm asking because in my case I need to add the group to a `SkinBase` subclass using `getChildren().add(Node)`. And a `Scene` object is sadly not a `Node`. Just putting the `Group` object into a dummy `Scene` and then not use it didn't work either..

Comment: The answer was in the comment section of my question. I just calculated the pixel width of the `String`.