# print text from textArea useing javaFX Printer

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am try to print text from text Area using JavaFX Printer(Like in notepad printing feature). I want to print that text without textArea background styles. So I try it with another text area. I wrap its text for avoid x bar overflow. But, I can't find a way to avoid y bar overflow. also I can't hide the background. can some one help or give a subjections for this or any other way. This is my current code. Also I try to hide scroll bars using css. but it did't support. I want to print only the text.

```
TextArea txtArea = new TextArea("This is some long text..");

public void printText() {

PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        
    if(job == null) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        return;
    }

    boolean proseed = job.showPrintDialog(root.getScene().getWindow());
        
    JobSettings ss1 = job.getJobSettings();
        
    PageLayout pageLayout1 = ss1.getPageLayout();
        
    double pgW1 = pageLayout1.getPrintableWidth();
    double pgH1 = pageLayout1.getPrintableHeight();

    TextArea tempTxtArea = new TextArea(txtArea.getText());
    tempTxtArea.setPrefSize(pgW1, pgH1);
    tempTxtArea.setWrapText(true);
    tempTxtArea.setId("tempScroolBar");

    if(proseed) {
        boolean printed = job.printPage(tempTxtArea);
            
        if (printed) {
            job.endJob();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
    }

}
```

this is my css file

```
#tempScroolBar > .scroll-pane {
    -fx-vbar-policy: never;
    -fx-hbar-policy: never;
}
```

[image: This is the current look of my output result]

**Update**

I updated my code. But now I have another problem. I changed TextArea to Label and to print all the content(avoid y bar overflow) I want to get number of the pages. But it doesn't return height(always return 0). Then I refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21075734/13862869 and I set It to the Scene. Without add the label to the new Scene it doesn't give the width. But when I set the label to the Scene only three '.' are print in my document. Can some one help me to solve this...

```
public void printText() {
        
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        
    if(job == null) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        return;
    }

    boolean proseed = job.showPrintDialog(root.getScene().getWindow());
        
    JobSettings ss1 = job.getJobSettings();
        
    PageLayout pageLayout1 = ss1.getPageLayout();
        
    double pgW1 = pageLayout1.getPrintableWidth();
    double pgH1 = pageLayout1.getPrintableHeight();

    HBox h = new HBox();
    Label tempText = new Label();
    tempText.setPrefWidth(pgW1);
    tempText.setWrapText(true);
    tempText.setText(txtArea.getText());
    h.getChildren().add(tempText);
    Scene s = new Scene(h); // when i remove this line again text can print
    tempText.applyCss();

    double fullLabelHeight = tempText.prefHeight(-1);
    int numberOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(fullLabelHeight/ pgH1);

    if(proseed) {
        job.printPage(tempText);
        job.endJob();
    }
}
```

Comment: See if the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918959/javafx-print-tableview-on-multiple-pages/37118619#37118619) helps.

Comment: Instead of trying to remove the GUI decorations through styling. create a new scene. Get the text from the TextArea and put it in a new Text or Label node in the new scene, then print the new scene.  You will also need to deal with pagination and scaling, which Sedrick’s comment may help with.

Comment: Thank you for both of you. I think, I will be able to do this with those ideas and answers.